# How to loop through split string

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How can I split a string on some delimiter and then loop through the parts? I tried a few functions and loop types with no success. I am trying to achieve something like:

```
create or replace function splitloop() returns void
as $$
DECLARE
part text;
BEGIN
   foreach part in string_to_array('one,two,three', ',')
   loop
      -- do something with part
   end loop;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should add word 'array' before actual array:

```
foreach part in array string_to_array('one,two,three', ',')
loop
    -- do something with part
end loop;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/63553/1)</kbd>**

documentation about [looping through arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you can recast your problems in terms of a set-based operation (plain SQL query), you should do so. `unnest()` is the key set-returning function. Can also be wrapped in an `sql` or `plpgsql` function. `plpgsql` syntax:

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT unnest(string_to_array('one,two,three', ','))
...
```

Details depend on *your* details.